# Can't call a method

Tags: java, methods

I just can't call the method "plus". I was trying to add more curly braces, also normal ones but nothing helped!

```
package example;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        int varTwo = b.nextInt();
        int varOne = a.nextInt();

        public static void plus (int aa, int bb) {
            return aa+bb;
            }
        plus(varOne, varTwo);
}

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    void is an invalid type for the variable plus
    Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
    Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
    Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
    Void methods cannot return a value
    The method plus(int, int) is undefined for the type HelloWorld

    at example.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:10)
```

Comment: You have written function inside main, write it outside main

Comment: You can't define a method inside a method.

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problems" means your program hasn't compiled.

Comment: Simply study the syntax rules more closely. You can't put a method declaration into another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have at the same time void method and return statement inside. If you want to return something from method remove void. Also code after return is unreachable and should be before return statement. Below fixed code that you can continue develop.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
    int varTwo = b.nextInt();
    int varOne = a.nextInt();
    int result = plus(varOne, varTwo);

   }
   public static int plus (int aa, int bb) {
      return aa+bb;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
package example;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        int varTwo = b.nextInt();
        int varOne = a.nextInt();


        plus(varOne, varTwo);
    }
    public static plus (int aa, int bb) {
        return aa+bb;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a method inside a method, try declaring `plus` outside of main (and getting rid of another `Scanner` as you won't need to `Scanner`s), e,g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int varOne = a.nextInt();
        int varTwo = a.nextInt();
        int sum = plus(varOne, varTwo);
        System.out.println(sum);
        a.close();
}

public static int plus (int aa, int bb) {
        return aa+bb;
}
```

Or better, you don't even need a method to perform a simple operation (unless specified), you can do it in `main` itself (also, you don't need two instances of `Scanner` as well), e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int varOne = a.nextInt();
        int varTwo = a.nextInt();
        int sum = varOne + varTwo;
        System.out.println(sum);
        a.close();
}
```

Comment: If the OP is trying to learn how to write and call a very simple method, getting rid of the method completely isn't really helpful.

Comment: That's why I mentioned `unless specified`. OP can still refer to my first solution.